# Bool type in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

In my DB I have a row `UserActive`. It is supposed to be bool. SQL Server does not support bool data type. The similar or close to it is `bit` 0/1. Ok if I'll make this column bit typed, then how I can handle with it in my C# code? Should I use bool type in my code?

Example

```
if (ud.UserActive != true)
{
   lblUserActive.Text = "Disactivated";
}
else
{
   lblUserActive.Text = "Activated";
}
```

or

```
if (ud.UserActive == 1)
{
   lblUserActive.Text = "Activated";
}
else
{
   lblUserActive.Text = "Disactivated";
}
```

Thank you for reply

Comment: SQL Server Data Type Mappings (ADO.NET): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Comment: "SQL does not support bool data" <-- What Database are you using? Microsoft SQL Server supports bool, it's called "bit". No idea about other databases.

Comment: Please edit the title to something more descriptive.

Comment: @Michael - `bit` is not a boolean datatype though in SQL Server itself as the OP correctly points out. You can't write `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE SomeBitColumn`, you must write  `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE SomeBitColumn = 1`

Comment: That's exactly what I thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second one.  C# is very strongly typed.

```
lblUserActive.Text = ud.UserActive != 0 ? "Activated" : "Not Activated";
```

Comment: But anyway,the type in SQL must be bit. Right?

Comment: You can make it any numeric type.  Bit works well, particularly if you have a number of them.  TINYINT works to and is going to be the same storage if you only have the one bit type column in the table.